# JS - iframe height with 100% and no scroll (Scroll-y in body)

Tags: javascript, iframe, height

I have an iframe problem. firstly I search the keyword `iframe height` in  https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=relevance&q=iframe%20height  but I did not find someone I need.

How to make an iframe wicth height with 100% and no scroll. Scroll-y in body.

```
<body style="scroll-x:hidden;scroll-y:auto;">
<iframe frameborder="0" id="iframe" scrolling="no" src="http://www.google.com" style="width:960px;height:100%" height="100%" width="960"></iframe>
```

And if I search something via http://www.google.com in the iframe, after turn to the google search result page. the iframe will calculate the new height and still with iframe height 100%, the scroll bar in the body part. (I wish some help could work perfect not only in ie and firefox, but also in safari and chrome ). Thanks a lot.

Comment: I'm a little confused. You want to make an iframe stretch over the entire contents of the window, and yet be scrollable? Is there any reason you can't just display the document contents in the window itself? Or are you omitting some vital piece of information here?

Comment: You want the scrollbar to be on the outer document, but you want it to control the iframe?

Answer (score 12):

This should do what you're looking for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Page Title</title>

    <style type="text/css" media="screen">

        body,
        html {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
        }

        * {
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
        }

        iframe {
            width: 960px;
            height: 100%;
            overflow: hidden;
            border: none;
        }
    </style>

</head>
<body>

    <iframe src="http://google.com" scrolling="no"></iframe>

</body>
</html>
```

The keys here are to:

- Make the BODY and HTML elements 100% of the browser window so when you make the iFrame 100%, it has something to be 100% of.
- Set the BODY and HTML elements to overflow:hidden so that no scrollbars are shown
- Make sure there is no padding

Hope that helps

Comment: so... the body have no scroll-y. If I search something in the iframe, I can only see the top few rows results, how do I see the rest?

Comment: Sorry, if you need to be able to scroll the body vertically, simply remove the overflow: hidden in the stylesheet rules for body, html.

Comment: I have tried, not work, the `iframe height` = `browser height`, so the scroll-y is not useful :(  I think it is over work for css...

Answer (score 3):

Use my JQuery Plugin :

```
 $.fn.resizeiframe=function(){
    $(this).load(function() {
        $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("body").height() );
    });
    $(this).click(function() {
        $(this).height( $(this).contents().find("body").height() );
    });

}
```

then , use it as following :

```
$('iframe').resizeiframe();
```

Don' forget to adjust attributes  of `iframe` as following :

```
<iframe
   src="islem.html"
   frameborder="0"
   width="100%"
   marginheight="0"
   marginwidth="0"
   scrolling="no"
></iframe>
```

Comment: This will most likely create a cross-origin block if requesting something outside your domain.

Answer (score 1):

I was searching for the same effect and I found a way. If you look with 'examine element' in Chrome (or firebug) in the metrics section, then select the  `<html>`. You should see if the html area is smaller than the whole document. If you set the html at height: 300%, it should work. Here are the important features:

```
html {height:300%;
}
body {height:100%;
}
#frame {height:90.74074074074074%;}
```

***watch for any max-height you might have coded, it would screw the effect up.

In my case, I had to split the frame height with another element in my container, so it could fully strech without scrollbars appearing. So I had to calculate the % of height remaining in my container, using firebug.

------- Another way, easier:

Try not specifying any height for BOTH your html documents,

```
html, body {}
```

then only code this:

```
#some-div {height:100%;}
#iframe {height:300%;}
```

note: the div should be your main section.

This should relatively work. the iframe does exactly calcultes 300% of the visible window height. If you html content from the 2nd document (in the iframe) is smaller in height than 3 times your browser height, it work. If you don't need to add content frequently to that document this is a permanent solution and you could just find your own % needed according to your content height.